# How to conditionalize a makefile based upon grep results?

Tags: makefile, grep

I'm looking for a way to bail out of a makefile if a certain string is not found when checking the version of a tool.

The grep expression I'm looking to match is:

```
dplus -VV | grep 'build date and time: Nov  1 2009 19:31:28'
```

which returns a matching line if the proper version of dplus is installed.

How do I work a conditional into my makefile based upon this expression?

Comment: Which make is this? gnu?

Comment: Yes. Specifically in Cygwin, but that's just GNU.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's another way that works in GNU Make:

```
DPLUSVERSION = $(shell dplus -VV | grep 'build date and time: Nov  1 2009 19:31:28')

target_of_interest: do_things do_things_that_uses_dplus

do_things:
    ...


do_things_that_uses_dplus:
ifeq ($(DPLUSVERSION),)
    $(error proper version of dplus not installed)
endif
    ...
```

This target can be something real, or just a PHONY target on which the real ones depend.

Comment: Worked a charm, and the ifeq...$(error...) let me spew an error message letting the developer know why their build was killed.

Comment: Warning! `$(error )` triggers when it is **evaluated**. that means, if `DPLUSVERSION` trigger the error condition, `do_things` will **never** run. edited to solve that. 
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html

Comment: @gcb: I don't think you tested your solution.

Comment: @Beta right, got carried away trying to do a quick edit. well, just did another quick edit without thinking too much, again :) it will probably run things out of order if `-j` is greater than 1... but should be OK now other than that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
.PHONY: check_dplus

check_dplus:
    dplus -VV | grep -q "build date and time: Nov  1 2009 19:31:28"
```

If grep finds no match, it should give

```
make: *** [check_dplus] Error 1
```

Then have your other targets depend on the check_dplus target.

Answer (score 2):

If this is [gnu make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), you can do

```
 your-target: $(objects)
     ifeq (your-condition)
         do-something
     else
         do-something-else
     endif
```

See here for [Makefile contionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example)

If your make doesn't support conditionals, you can always do

```
 your-target:
     dplus -VV | grep -q "build date and time: Nov  1 2009 19:31:28" || $(MAKE) -s another-target; exit 0
     do-something

 another-target:
     do-something-else
```