# Grep exit codes in Makefile

Tags: makefile, grep, exit-code

I would like to check the result of a grep search in a Makefile. Contrary to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876890/how-to-conditionalize-a-makefile-based-upon-grep-results), I do not wish to use the shell command.
Also, I don't want the Makefile to raise an error when grep do not find the string (exit code of 1 is treated as an error).

The following tries to ignore the error and check the exit code :

```
all:
    -grep term log* 
    echo $$?
    @case "$$?" in \
      0)\
    echo "found";; \
    *) \
    echo "not found";;\
    esac;
```

Unfortunately, the exit code is always 0.

Comment: Oh I have been searching for this! Made my day. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The separate lines of a series of actions in a `makefile` are normally executed in separate sub-shells.  To code what you're after, then:

```
all:
    if grep term log*; \
    then echo found; \
    else echo not found; \
    fi
```

That's a single command; it tests the exit status of `grep` directly.  Note the liberal use of semi-colons; that's necessary because it all gets flattened when passed to the shell.  Note too that the `-` is not needed; the statement as a whole exits with status 0 because one of the `echo` commands is executed, succeeds, and that is the status returned from the sub-shell.  But there's another part to the trick; IIRC, the script is invoked with `/bin/sh -e` so the script exits on the first error (non-zero) status from a shell command — except in explicit conditionals such as an `if`.

If you want to explicitly capture the status of `grep` (if only to be sure it's being done right), then:

```
all:
    -grep term log*; \
    status=$$?; echo $$status; \
    if [ $$status = 0 ]; \
    then echo found; \
    else echo not found; \
    fi
```

You probably need the `-` this time because the `grep` is not executed as part of a shell conditional and a non-zero exit status could trigger the `-e` processing.  I don't recommend futzing with this.

You might note that you can do `cd` commands in an action and because each action is executed separately, you have to do it repeatedly.

```
install:  ${PROG}
    cd ${INSTBIN}; ${RM_F} ${PROG}
    ${CP} ${PROG} ${INSTBIN}
    cd ${INSTBIN}; ${CHOWN} ${OWNER}:${GROUP} ${PROG}; ${CHMOD} ${PERMS} ${PROG}
```

Yes, you can do it differently — I'm demonstrating a point, not advocating a style of installing programs.

Comment: The first solution is very elegant. With the detailled explanation, accepted !
I do not understant the point in the last paragraph, though.

Comment: Instead of doing `cd ${INSTBIN}; ${RM_F} ${PROG}`, I could write: `${RM_F} ${INSTBIN}/${PROG}` without a `cd` at all.  That's all I'm saying.  (I work on makefiles where that is basically how the code is copied from a build area — by root, to my disgust — to the distribution directory. I won't bore you with how it got like that and why I haven't fixed it yet.)

Comment: In my limited experience of Makefile, the only use of cd is to call a sub-Makefile.

Comment: @alex_reader: Keep it that way, but also remember [Recursive `make` Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/).